# Deploying to AppServicePlan Functions from Azure Pipelines takes a long time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

'm deploying my application to Azure Functions using the pipeline below.
Deploying to Functions in the Consumption plan completes the deployment stage in less than a minute, but deploying to Functions in the App Service Plan takes more than 10 minutes to deploy.

Why is it taking so long to deploy to Functions in AppServicePlan from Azure Pipelines?

```
yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
resources:
- repo: self
variables:
  pythonVersion: 3.6
  serviceConnetion: 'subscription'
  functionAppName: 'functionAppName'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'
pool:
    vmImage: $(vmImageName)
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build stage'
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: $(pythonVersion)
    - bash: |
        python -m venv worker_venv
        source worker_venv/bin/activate
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Develop stage'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(serviceConnetion)'
              appType: 
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
```

Comment: This could be the result of insufficient capacity in your App Service plan.  You can try to scale up the App Service instance to increase available CPU, RAM, and disk space or try with a different App Service plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remote build may be enabled, please disable
it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#remote-build